# How do I make a bot respond to a specific reaction? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a giveaway function to my discord bot but the reroll function I am trying to make does not work. When the giveaway ends it sends a message that says who won the giveaway. This is what I have defined as reroll. Then I make the bot wait and see if someone has added a 'x' reaction to this message. I am trying to make it so that if someone has added an 'x' reaction then it will redo the winner choice in the giveaway. I hope to also make this function repeat if multiple winners are invalid. But I am not exactly sure how I would make a bot respond specifically to a specific reaction on a message.

```
reroll = await channel.send(f'Congratulations! {winner.mention} won {prize}!')

if reroll.reactions == '❌':

    winner2 = random.choice(users)

    await channel.send(f'Congratulations! {winner2.mention} won {prize}!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [discord documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add), we can check `on_reaction_add(reaction, user)`.

> Called when a message has a reaction added to it. Similar to
> on_message_edit(), if the message is not found in the internal message
> cache, then this event will not be called. Consider using
> on_raw_reaction_add() instead.

With that you can basically check for the message

```
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  if 'Congratulations!' in reaction.message.content and reaction.emoji == '❌':
    # do stuff
```

You can access the Message being reacted via `Reaction.message`

Comment: `reaction.message.content`